# select statement intermittently returns null

Tags: mysql

So I have the following code in a stored procedure:

```
set @Id = (select id from foo where Name = 'bar');
IF @Id is null THEN
     #add missing record
END IF;
```

However, its seems that the database will only return a value intermittently.  Even when I know my select statement will return a record (copied and pasted directly out of my stored proc).  Has anyone else had this issue with MySQL?

about the only crazy thing my proc is doing:
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR 1062, 1452

but neither of those should effect my query (I am sure there is one and only one record)

Thanks

Comment: in mysql 8.0.18 it works fine.but i limited it to 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO i don't know why this fixed the problem, but it did.

By setting the variable to null first before the assignment seems to have fixed the problem.  I was have the problem intermittently, so maybe I'm just lucking out longer than I did last time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a stored procedure like the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE example_proc (pName VARCHAR(10))
BEGIN
  IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM foo WHERE Name = pName) THEN
    INSERT INTO foo (Name) VALUES (pName);
  END IF;
END
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=777d4b15ec6d34020178fc6166f7a065)

Comment: Mine does work, but it just works intermittently.  That's the read head scratcher.